# What is meant by this "will"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, modal-verbs

> Let the gentle, kindly phantoms haunt us as they **will**; we are not afraid of them.
>    [*Source*](http://www.literaturepage.com/read/idlethoughts-106.html)

I an confused about the phrase "as they will" – does this "will" means *an intention*?
Like, "all they want?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pretty much yes, it's a rather archaic verb form of 'will' as noun -

> **will**
> Pronunciation: /wɪl/
> *noun*
> "the thing that one desires or ordains:"
> *Jane tells St. John that she could marry him if she only knew it was God’s will*
>
> *verb*
> [with object]
> chiefly formal or literary intend, desire, or wish (something) to happen:
> *their friendship flourished particularly because Adams willed it*
>
> **Phrases**
>
> **at will**
> at whatever time or in whatever way one pleases:
>  *he seemed to think he could walk in and out of her life at will*

In your context "as they will" is a somewhat archaic phrase meaning "whatever way they want".

You'll nowadays find this expression in the fundamental tenet of the Wiccan faith:

> Wiccan morality is expressed in a brief statement found within a text called the Wiccan Rede: "An it harm none, do what you will."

It means: Do whatever you want, just don't harm anyone.

Another common phrase where you hear it is military "Fire at will" - order to open fire at the enemy picking targets of opportunity - not salvos, not cover fire, you pick your targets, and moments to shoot.

Comment: If I understand correctly, there was no future tense in Old English. Even in modern English, when I hear someone says "I will ...", I still got an impression that he "choose" to do that (by his own will). Am I correct about these?

Comment: I can't say anything about Old English, but in modern the "intent" part is long dead - if you want to imply intent, you use "is going to" although the two are usually interchangeable.

Comment: Yes, you're right -- the modern use of "will" for future evolved from this old use. However, that evolution has long since happened, so there's nothing at all strange sounding in a sentence like "I will go to the store tomorrow, even though I don't want to."

Comment: In the US, at least, we also talk about a job being "an at-will job", meaning that you have no contract, so you can quit at any time and they can fire you at any time.

Comment: @snailboat: outside of "to will something into existence" and the few idiomatic phrases it's very rarely used, replaced almost entirely by "wish", "desire", "want", "like"